# How to differentiate between key and value while parsing JSON string using rapidjson?

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm parsing a JSON string using "rapidjson". 
I'm studying following example of SAX type parsing of json object.

https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/75cee948d44876f22f7215b9bd64733c3d7fee51/example/simplereader/simplereader.cpp

In this SAX type parsing rapidjson calls the event handler for each data type as received whiling parsing.(as documents at (https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/2e0b3de8d68758b2866fff5f047c893b8a1c4290/doc/sax.md)

How I can differentiate that given element is key and value corresponding to that key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only differentiate the keys and values by the order of event sequence.

When the `Reader` (SAX Parser) encounters an JSON object, it calls `StartObject()` of the handler. Then there will be a sequence of key-value pairs. The key must be a `String()` call, but the value can be any JSON value types. And finally it calls `EndObject()`.

So, you need to keep track of the state of the parsing. For simple structure, it just need a an enum to represent the current state. For recursive structure, you may need a custom stack.

In [this section](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/2e0b3de8d68758b2866fff5f047c893b8a1c4290/doc/sax.md#parsing-json-to-custom-data-structure-customdatastructure), it shows an example of parsing a simple object into a custom data structure. And it needs to handle 3 states. Or, you may use a counter for number of calls to `String()` and uses odd/even to determine whether it is key or value.

Using SAX API may be more difficult sometimes. On the other hand, it provides better performance and less memory overheads.

---

Update: 2014/9/5

A pull-request which adds a `Key()` event in additional to `String()` has been [merged](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/commit/5e03cbf1b3a9c25129593891e1b4ca4db2203951). The new interface shall simplify writing custom handlers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the ans.. I might use enum as suggested in your example.